# Shared configuration for Eclipse on Debian server

Tags: debian, configuration, user-management, eclipse

I've manually installed the latest Eclipse on our debian server and wanted to configure it so all users share the same configuration. It turned out less obvious than I thought: I don't seem to be able to install packages for all users. If I run it myself, all configuration data is saved under my own home directory. If I run Eclipse using sudo, everything is saved under the root directory but is not accessible for other users when they run Eclipse.

I've been browsing the manual of Eclipse and some forums, but apart from a "yes, you can" I couldn't find any information on *how* that should be done. The biggest problem is installing plugins for all users to be found. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Eclipse : 3.6.1 classic, installed using [this procedure](http://www.sumardi.net/2007/07/08/how-to-install-eclipse-33-manually/).

Server uname: GNU/Linux *** 2.6.26-2-amd64

Server is accessed using Putty, and Gnome desktop through realVNC. Just mentioning it if that is of any importance. Our sysadmin is on "prolonged leave" (working in Spain and never replaced), so I'm stuck without help here.

EDIT : --  I asked this question also on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679159/shared-configuration-for-eclipse-on-debian-server) as I wasn't certain this is a genuine server-related question. Please feel free to merge both questions at the appropriate place. --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it turned out that it was rather impossible to get this set up due to the internal structure of Eclipse. We set up Eclipse and created an executable in /usr/bin so all users could fire up Eclipse easily. Installed plugins were available for all users, but every user had to manually set the configuration for the plugins.